# How to make my discord bot read from a file and paste it in a discord chat on command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I am making my discord bot with python and i want my bot to read a notepad file present on my desktop and write everything from the notepad file to the chatbox when the command is typed. Please tell me how I can do it!

Thanks :-)

P.S Make sure to DM me on discord, if you know how to do it, it would mean the world to me!!!!!
TOG6#6666

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and you should (re-)read the help topic [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to get a feeling on how to contribute. You should at least make an own attempt to get your task done and share the code here. Even if you don't have a good knowledge about Python.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it, hopefully works!

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    file = open(r"C:\\User\path", "r")
    content = file.read()
    await ctx.send(content)
```

You don't need to close the file if you're reading it.

Answer (score 0):

you can read the file like this

```
f = open("demofile.txt", "r")
print(f.read())
```

to post the lines into the discord chat, you have use the discord api

your code would help us more. Have tried to do anything yet? Maybe try to make your app first and then ask us to help with the specific problems... we cant do the whole app for you :))

Comment: but, once it read the file, how do i make it write everything from the notepad file onto the discord chat?

Comment: I'm soo sorry for bein a bot, but do you have discord, I would really appreciate it if you could lend me a hand, you have no idea how much i'd appreciate!

Comment: As I said, read the discord api, posting a message into a chat should be very easy with it. All the informations you need are in the discord api documentation. Please, try to implement if by yourself first, or read/watch some tutorials. I am sure you will find a lot. here is the api doc that tells you how to post a message into chat https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message

Comment: pls help me buddy, i tried i just need help fixing a line or two, thats all, im begging u, really

Comment: if you need help fixing a line of two, post your code here, i am sure we will be able to help you here

Comment: import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("The bot is ready to run!")

@client.command()
async def nitro(ctx):
    f = open("nitro codes.txt", "r")
    await ctx.send(f.read())


client.run('token')

Comment: how do i send it like u sent it? neatly with indentation?

Answer (score 0):

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    file = open(r"C:\\User\path", "rt")
    content = file.read()
    file.close()
    await ctx.send(content)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.